# How to set cumulative Screen Time Allowances?

Tags: iphone, parental-controls, screen-time

I am setting up screen time with parental controls for our family. 
I would like to grant the following allowance to a user:

- All apps and categories: 30mins
- Camera app + 15mins
- Photos app + 15mins

What happens now is that the "All apps" allowance seems to include camera and photo time – even if the user hasn't touched camera in 30 minutes of usage, access is blocked after this time. So it seems to rather read:

- All apps and categories: 30mins
  -- of which:
  -- Camera app not more than 15mins
  -- Photos app not more than 15mins

This is not what I intended. But I also don't want to fully allow Camera and Photos. How can I add time for a specific app "on top" of the general allowance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if it's always been like that, but with current macOS Catalina 10.15 it's possible to combine app groups. Just DON'T use "All apps".

The first limit is "Everything" (all groups except social networks), the second limit is "social networks". This will then be added.

[image]

Also, it has become very easy to select single apps:

[image]